# deployerConfigContext for CAS 5 version

Tags: cas

We have custom CAS 3.4 version configured with deployerConfigContext.xml. Authentication Manager and multiple authentication handlers are registered in deployerConfigContext.xml. We are migrating to CAS 5.3.X version. Questions 1) Will CAS 5.3.x supports Spring deployerConfigContext.xml ? 2) How do we implement deployerConfigContext.xml in CAS 5.3.X ? Can you please pint me some sample configuration XML files in CAS 5.3.x version.

Answer (score 1):

1) No
2) Via auto-configuration modules provided by CAS or your own.
3) No such examples exists, nor will they ever.

Please read https://apereo.github.io/2017/02/21/cas-autocfg-strategy/